# How can I structure the interface?

Tags: json, go, multidimensional-array

I have this json array and I need to extract the data:

```
b := [[{"client": " 321"}], [{"number": "3123"}]]
```

How can I structure the interface?

```
var f interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f)

f = map[string]interface{}{

----> ?

}
```

Comment: https://gobyexample.com/json

Comment: You can structure it however you want. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

You can test the code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Qx3hkUR6vu).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    // test input (json.Unmarshal expects []byte)
    b := []byte("[[{\"client\": \" 321\"}], [{\"number\": \"3123\"}]]")

    // declare the target variable in the correct format
    var f [][]map[string]string

    // unmarshal the json
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // output result
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

For details see the comments in the code. Feel free to ask.

Comment: I did not know how to access the data and thought it had to be done through a structure. Your answer helped me with what I was looking for

fmt.Println(f[0][0]["client"])      ----->  321
fmt.Println(f[1][0]["number"])  ----->3123

Thank's a lot!